# How much longer would it take to reach technological parity without access to energy dense resources like fossil fuels to bootstrap development?

Tags: physics, alternate-worlds, chemistry, scientific-development

If the only difference in our hypothetical world is where fossil fuels like coal and crude oil are nonexistent, the advent of an analogous Renaissance Era, subsequent Age of Enlightenment, and Scientific Revolution would be unaffected as those result purely from the existence of a long enough period of agricultural stability and wind based sail transportation, agricultural stability allowing for the development of stable bases of continued knowledge accumulation and wind based sail transportation converting localized bases of knowledge accumulation into shared singular globalized knowledge accumulation through dispersal of information and communication across connected sea trading routes.

Assuming humanity in this scenario is no less intelligent, how much longer would it take to reach technological parity in the present day? I would guess that the importance of physics and chemistry progress from scientists born for the development of energy storage mechanisms like batteries is significantly magnified. Exploitation of fossil fuels allowed for exponential population growth, and more people means more scientists which means faster research and development times. Without such a bootstrap, I imagine population levels would be bottlenecked largely within the range of peak Renaissance / Age of Enlightenment before the first Industrial Revolution. How much would this have slowed scientific development in our hypothetical world?

To me it seems that the only two avenues that would replicate the likes of exponential growth in energy access that the exploitation of fossil fuels provided is either nuclear or solar power. Once either of those are discovered through proper chemistry/physics developments in electromagnetism and atomic nuclei understanding, technology growth rates would come in line with ours. The question is how long it would take to reach that point with scientific development slowed to such a degree.

Also, without things like plastics that primarily derive from fossil fuels what does the world look like as technology develops? Civilization centered around areas of hydroelectric power sources until nuclear/solar powered steam punk?

Comment: Hi Lawrence, I'm a bit worried that this question might be a bit too broad because there are many consequences of not having fossil fuels. Fossil fuel is a key part of World War 2 with the heavy use of aircraft and armored vehicles and ships. Without the development of these technologies, we would likely stagnate in our technological developments (Nuclear was military driven. Without the means to delivery a Nuke, we would of never developed it). This is followed by the USA backing its currency with OIL instead of Gold as many countries did before. The consequences are far too wide ranging.

Comment: I agree. You cannot predict *when* (not to mention *whether*) someone would have gotton the right idea on how to use nuclear power if noone ever got the idea of burning coal in a steam engine before. The technological advancement could be delayed by hundreds of years or could have overcome our level by now.

Comment: Biofuels are more likely than solar or nuclear power — they’re a natural extension of the burning of wood and charcoal.

Comment: @Shadowzee But I recall that electric cars where already being developed when fossil fuels took over and made electric technology obsolete until today. Surely, without fossil fuels we wouldn't have just stagnated. I have to make more research about this before answering.

Comment: If you can read French, this comic is a good reference they explored a similar idea https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vive_l%27empereur_!  (the exclamation mark is part of the link but SE won't include it ...)

Comment: Coal is a fossil fuel. Without coal there would have been no industrial revolution, next to no mass production, much less specialization of jobs. Sure, you could power your machinery with wood, but you'd need more of it, and constructing the machinery would also take longer, since creating the materials would take longer, too. No fossil fuels also would reduce the propability of global war, leading to less scientific developments etc.

Comment: Looking at Japan ad their method of producing "better" coal AND their technological advancement I would say that you wouldn't even have industrial revolution. Because it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Worth noting that decent metallurgy requires high energy density materials: so this world will have a much lower rate of metal production. It’s possible your renaissance simply won’t start without access to some form of easily accessible refined carbon, unless you’re going to have a veritable army of charcoal burners.

Comment: another way of coming at this is from the post-apocalyptic scenario of a civilization re-emerging from near scratch long after bulk hydrocarbon resources have been exhausted.  its a very interesting thought experiment.

Comment: @MikeScott Biofuels are a form of solar power : plants convert sunlight to chemicals, and we burn the chemicals to get the energy back. Unfortunately, the efficiency is pretty low, and there is simply not enough arable surface for the energy needs of a modern society. Fossil fuels are what was stored during the Carboniferous era, between the appearance of forests and the appearance of organisms capable of decomposing cellulose - making it literally the world's biggest solar-powered energy storage. This is what allows industry since the XIXe Century to bypass the area surface limitation.

Comment: They could have made slightly better with stuff like mechanical wind and hydraulic generators and other (for us) renewable, storing energy as compressed gas. But windmills had very low efficiency, you can only build so many dams, and compressed gas is both high-loss and low-efficiency per mass or volume storage (even if it is better than primitive batteries), so it would still not have been enough for fuel anything remotely as big as like the historical industrial revolution.

Comment: @theRiley Mineral deposits would be different as well: natural ones would be depleted, but ancient ruins would make for new ones, with different composition. I wonder what glass mines would look like?

Comment: Remember that petroleum derivatives are used in all kinds of industrial chemical processes, including but not limited to the production of most plastics, the production of modern fertilizers, and the production of many pharmaceuticals. Before electricity, whale oil and other organic oils were replaced by cleaner-burning (and somewhat less species-wiping-out) kerosene and natural gas light. Natural gas and petroleum-derived heating oil has replaced coal has replaced wood for keeping us warm when it's cold. And if you're running windmills etc for electricity... What are you using as a lubricant?